# golang read files in linux with parent process namespace

Tags: linux, go, cgo

I have used the setns system call in linux to set the current go process's NET namespace. This namespace changes the way /sys/class/net appears to the current process. However, If I try to view these files with the golang apis, I see only the parent's view (not namespaced). I think this is because go is forking without inheriting the parent's namespace. How can I read the files in /sys/class/net with go such that the setns system call persists in the child who is reading the file.

Comment: I wanted to write a answer but i also found out somebody else already wrote a good article about namespaces. It can be found here : https://medium.com/@teddyking/namespaces-in-go-basics-e3f0fc1ff69a

Answer (score 0):

turns out this a known 'wontfix' issue in go: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8676

the workaround I found was to use cgo to fork in a c function exposed to go runtime and then call setns.